# How to add if statement in filter?

Tags: python, django

I have 4 parameters: city, province, strtype, direction, when the parameter is not empty I want to use it in filter, when it is empty, do not set it as filter keyword.

The part of current code I use is as below:

```
if (direction == '') & (strtype == '') & (city == '') & (province == ''):
    queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__startswith=keyword)[:10]
    if not queryset.exists():
        queryset = address.objects.filter(strname__startswith=keyword)[:10]
        return queryset
    else:
        return queryset

if (direction != '') & (strtype == '') & (city == '') & (province == ''):
    queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__startswith=keyword, 
                                      strdir=direction)[:10]
    if not queryset.exists():
        queryset = address.objects.filter(strname__startswith=keyword, 
                                          strdir=direction)[:10]
        return queryset
    else:
        return queryset
```

There are 16 posibilities, it means i need to write 16 if statements! This is too many codes and ungraceful, is there a terse solution?

Comment: BTW the logical AND operator in python is `and` and not `&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build a dictionary and then pass it as keyword parameters using the double-star syntax `f(**kwargs)`:

```
conds = {}
if direction != '': conds["strdir"] = direction
if strtype != '': conds["strtype"] = strtype
if province != '': conds["province"] = province
if city != '': conds["city"] = city
queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__startswith=keyword, 
                                  **conds)[:10]
if not queryset.exists():
    queryset = address.objects.filter(strname__startswith=keyword, 
                                      **conds)[:10]
```

Comment: awesome! this is really terse and I don't need to write 16 if statements finally! Really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> There are 16 posibilities, it means i need to write 16 if statements!

**No!**, not if these parameters act more or less independent. We can for example first abstract common logic away:

```
def add_custom_filters(qs, direction, strtype, city, province):
    if direction:
        qs = qs.filter(strdir=direction)
    if strtype:
        qs = qs.filter(strype=strtype)
    if city:
        qs = qs.filter(strcity=city)
    if privince:
        qs = qs.filter(strprov=privince)
    return qs
```

(might need some altering)

So now we can use this logic like:

```
queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__startswith=keyword)
queryset = add_custom_filters(queryset, direction, strtype, city, province)[:10]
if not queryset:
    queryset = address.objects.filter(strname__startswith=keyword)
    queryset = add_custom_filters(queryset, direction, strtype, city, province)[:10]
return queryset
```

We thus only need four `if` cases, and we reuse this function for the two-attempt approach.

Since filtering if not *truthiness* is True is a common pattern, we can encapsulate this in a helper function:

```
def filter_if_truthfull(qs, **kwargs):
    retrurn qs.filter(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v})
```

then we can use it like:

```
queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__startswith=keyword)
queryset = filter_if_truthfull(queryset, strdir=direction, strtype=strtype, strcity=city, strprov=province)[:10]
if not queryset:
    queryset = address.objects.filter(strname__startswith=keyword)
    queryset = filter_if_truthfull(queryset, strdir=direction, strtype=strtype, strcity=city, strprov=province)[:10]
return queryset
```

This allows us to add an arbitrary amount of *named* filter criteria that are only applied in case the value has truthiness true (for a string, this happens if the string not empty, in case it is `None`, it is not a string, but these filters are also not considered).

In case you are going to use the results of a `QuerySet` anyway, it is better to check `if queryset`, since this will perform a query, that loads the elements into the queryset as well, whereas `.exists()` will query with an `EXISTS` query, and if you want to process the elements later, you need to perform an extra query to fetch them in memory.